# How can we prevent RoutingSlipFaulted to be fired when a single specific RoutingSlipActivity faulted?

Tags: masstransit, routing-slip

We have a routing slip that contains several dynamically generated activities. We receive a `RoutingSlipFaulted` event when any of these activities fault - this is the documented default and perfectly fine for most of our requirements.

We now have a case where each of these activities might fail and the execution of the subsequent activities in the routing slip should continue. The [documentation](https://masstransit.io/documentation/patterns/routing-slip#faulting) says about this:

> By default, if an activity throws an exception, it will be faulted and a RoutingSlipFaulted event will be published (unless a subscription changes the rules).

But how exactly do you "change the rules" on the subscription?

We're using a `RoutingSlipBuilder` instance to create the routing slip, adding activities and a subscription like this:

```cs
public virtual RoutingSlip BuildRoutingSlip()
{
    var builder = new RoutingSlipBuilder(Id);

    // add activities
    foreach (var activity in _activities)
    {
        [...]
        builder.AddActivity(activity.Name, endpointAddress, argumentsObject);
    }

    // add monitoring subscription
    builder.AddSubscription(Endpoints.GetEndpoint<Transaction>(),
        RoutingSlipEvents.Completed | RoutingSlipEvents.Faulted | RoutingSlipEvents.ActivityCompleted | RoutingSlipEvents.ActivityFaulted,
        RoutingSlipEventContents.All);

    return builder.Build();
}
```

Where and how would we configure the subscription to continue the routing slip execution when an activity fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an activity failing should not fault the routing slip, that activity should not throw an exception. It must call `Completed` regardless of what happens inside the activity (exceptions, or otherwise).

The subscription has *nothing* to do with the routing slip execution behavior, it's purely for delivering routing slip events.

Comment: That was quick, thank you very much. A follow up question: what exactly does the cited "unless a subscription changes the rules" mean in this context?

Comment: Subscriptions can prevent events from being published if they are only sent to the subscription address. It's all in the subscription options.